Display List GUID and List Name In SharePoint Online Column in View
I'm trying to display the list name and the list GUID in the default view of a SharePoint Online list. Is this possible? I haven't found a calculated column method or JSON formatting method but I thought there might be one. Seems difficult.

I don't think there is any way to get list name or GUID using calculated column formula or JSON formatting in SharePoint Online. You can get web/site URL using @currentWeb in JSON formatting but there is no way to get list name/URL/GUID, etc.

can I just add @currentWeb reference? I'm having trouble seeing that displayed to see what that gives me. Should it be $currentWeb in the JSON formatting?

Nevermind. I have that portion working now. Yes, it doesn't give the title.

The list GUID and list name are the same for all elements in a given SPO list. Would it be an option to use a default value for your column?

if the default value can be automatically populated but I'm not sure it can. It has to be something that automatically points/and populates those values @grisha
